# Model always null when passing model from Ajax (BeginForm) to controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am new to C# ASP.Net MVC stuff having come from Java/Spring. I am having issues currently binding a model to the form and passing it through. It's always coming in to the controller as null. I've tried various things to no avail. Must be something simple I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

// View

```
@model BensHub.Models.VisitorMessage
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
                "PostMessage",
                "VisitorBoard",
                new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
            {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(msg => msg.Name, new { @class = "board- 
                field", @style = "margin-top:8px;", @minlength 
                             ="1",maxlength = "28", placeholder ="Name" })

                @Html.TextAreaFor(msg => msg.Message, new { @class = 
                "board-field", @rows = "4", @minlength = "1", @maxlength = 
                "128",  @placeholder = "Something nice?", })

                <input class="board-submit" type="submit" value="Say It"/>
            }
```

// Controller

```
namespace BensHub.Controllers
{
public class VisitorBoardController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostMessage(VisitorMessage message)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }

        return Json(message);
    }
}
}
```

// Route

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "MessagePost",
            "VisitorBoard/PostMessage",
            new { controller = "VisitorBoard", action = "PostMessage" }
        );
```

// Model

```
namespace BensHub.Models
{
    public class VisitorMessage
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(28, MinimumLength = 1)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(128, MinimumLength = 1)]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code look okay to me have you added jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js

Comment: Yep     <!-- Javascript -->
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryunobtrusive")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")  - This includes the script for the unobtrusive ajax also

Comment: If you are sure you have mapped correctly your object's `properties` then you could also try using   `public ActionResult PostMessage([FromBody] VisitorMessage message)`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so, I figured out this issue for anybody interested.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostMessage(VisitorMessage message)
```

The action parameter 'message' conflicts with a property of the same name in the model sending the model binder crazy etc. Just rename it to something else, or the property name.

Answer (score 0):

I copy and pasted the code you provided into a new project and it works as expected! Something that you haven't posted here is whats causing the issue. I would double check your routes, mine are setup as follows:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    "MessagePost",
    "VisitorBoard/PostMessage",
    new { controller = "VisitorBoard", action = "PostMessage" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The order of the routes will affect which one gets hit, if i were to swap the order of my bottom two routes then a different action would get called

Comment: Strange as if I use your mappings then it doesn't even hit the controller, the action url in the ajax request is just localhost:49397/ and does nothing. The values seem to be entered into the Model state but it is also set as invalid

Comment: Ah sorry, my post was unclear, I was pointing it at my HomeController. If you put this as your very first route it should fix your problem i think:

`routes.MapRoute(
            "MessagePost",
            "VisitorBoard/PostMessage",
            new { controller = "VisitorBoard", action = "PostMessage" }
        );`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should add `[FromBody]` attribute before your input parameter:

```
public class VisitorBoardController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostMessage([FromBody] VisitorMessage message)
    { // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't make any difference, still comes in as null ! hmm